# Looping a javascript function onload

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop, countdown

I want to call a `Javascript` as many times as needed inside a `PHP` while loop. I'm trying to figure out the proper way to call multiple instances of the function on load.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    var interval;
    var minutes = 1;
    var seconds = 10;
    var nbcounters = '<?php echo $nbcounters ;?>'
    window.onload = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < nbcounters; i++) {
            countdown('c'.'<?php echo $value ;?>');
        }
     }


     function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                location.reload(true);
                 } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
             }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' min(s)' : ' min');
                var secound_text = '';
                el.innerHTML = 'Ready in ' + minute_text;
            } else {
                 var minute_text = '';
                var second_text = seconds + (seconds > 1 ? ' sec(s)' : ' sec');
                el.innerHTML = 'Ready in ' + second_text;
             }
             seconds--;
         }, 1000);
     }
  </script>
 <?php
 $nbcounters = 5;
 $value = 0;
 while ($value < $nbcounters) {
    echo "<div id='c$value'></div><br>";
    $value++;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing when to use `php` loop and when `js` loop. Basically use the `php` loop to generate `N` calls to the `js` function like here:

```
window.onload = function() {
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nbcounters; $i++) {
        echo "countdown('c".<?php echo $i ;?>."');";
    }
    ?>
 }
```

this will result in html like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    countdown('c0');
    countdown('c1');
    countdown('c2');
    countdown('c3');
    countdown('c4');
}
```

but be sure to first set you `php` parameters before this loop.